# Replace character with a special char in a string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I am trying to program a simple python code to get a string from the user and return the string where all the occurrences of its first character have been changed to " * ", expect the first char itself!

Example: "babble" yields "ba**le"

```
def main():
    string = raw_input("Enter a string:")
    string_len = len(string)
    string_final = range(0,string_len-1)

    for i in range(0,string_len-1):
        if string[0] == string[i+1]:
           string_final[i] = "*"
        else:
            string_final[i] = string[i]
    print string_final

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output is

```
>>> 
[u'b', '*', '*', u'b', u'l']
```

I am expecting the output to be

```
["b" "a" "*" "*" "l" "e"]
```

Can someone tell me, what am I missing here?

Comment: You're comparing against `string[i+1]`, but assigning with `string[i]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are comparing the character at `i + 1`, do copy that character when not matching the original first, not the one at `i`:

```
if string[0] == string[i + 1]:
    string_final[i] = "*"
else:
    string_final[i] = string[i + 1]  # copy the character at i + 1
```

This could be simplified to:

```
string_final[i] = "*" if string[0] == string[i + 1] else string[i + 1]
```

Your loop never includes that first character into `string_final` of course; you could just use `.append()` calls instead of pre-building the list with `range()`:

```
string = raw_input("Enter a string:")
string_final = string[:1]

for i in range(0, len(string) - 1):
    string_final.append("*" if string[0] == string[i+1] else string[i+1])

print string_final
```

To do your function in one line, requires using `str.join()` and a list comprehension with the same conditional expression:

```
string_final = string[0] + ''.join(['*' if s == string[0] else s for s in string[1:]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I do not want to remove the first occurrence itself! I want to remove only the subsequent occurrences! Please check the example input & output I mentioned above the code!

Comment: @anishjp: then start `string_final` with that first character, you are not considering it when building the list. `print string[:1] + string_final` would show it.

Comment: I liked your one line statement, but I have concern though! If I just take the condition expression alone ["*" if s == string[0] else s for s in string[1:]] When the if statement is executed, shouldn't it complain about the value of s not defined?

Comment: @anishjp: no, that's a list comprehension; the whole expression before the `for s in string[1:]` loop is executed for each iteration of the `for` loop; `s` is defined by the `for` loop part.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do that as:

```
def a(your_str):
    return your_str[0]+''.join(['*' if i==your_str[0] else i for i in your_str[1:]])
```

#### Examples:

```
>>> a('babble')
'ba**le'

>>> a('tomato')
'toma*o'

>>> a('hehehe')
'he*e*e'
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use `string.replace`.

```
>>> s = "babble"
>>> s[0] + s[1:].replace(s[0], "*")
```

output:

```
'ba**le'
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me how to achieve the same result using a different built-in function.